# Is there a way to work around Android store's 2 hour latency for publishing alpha versions?

Tags: android, testing

I'm currently using the Android store to distribute alpha versions of my app to testers.  It works but the latency is unpredictable and long.  Sometimes it's two hours.  Sometimes the app won't download till they uninstall it and try reinstalling.  Sometimes it becomes available on one device but not another.

I completely understand the need for Google to check for viruses and schedule downloads for production releases.  But for a handful of testers?  Testers need it now, not tomorrow.

Is there a work around for Google's latency?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but there is [**Beta** from **Twitter's fabric**](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/introduction.html). Basically, you have to install the fabric plugin to your android studio, register your app in fabric, then you have to create an apk which you will upload to fabric. You will have to register the tester's email.